# Set Drawable background for a button on the RemoteView

Tags: android, remoteview

I can set the background for a button on the remoteViews by using setInt method with Drawbale Id in the Drawable folder:

```
 remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btn_avatar, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.button_image);
```

I am trying to set the background for the button by:

- Taking a photo by camera
- Convert bitmap photo to Drawable and set it to the Button

  `Drawable drawableIcon = new BitmapDrawable(this.context.getResources(), myBitmap);`

The problem is that the `drawableIcon` object does not has R.drawable Id to use with `setInt` method.
Can you please suggest me another method to set the drawableIcon object as button Background.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

RemoteView have api below

```
setImageViewBitmap(int viewId, Bitmap bitmap)
```

try this method. no need to convert Drawable.

Comment: I want to set the circle image and I do not get desired result with bitmap, the button show only a small part of the image and it is still a square, not a circle.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, instead of using only one button, I use a button for the Drawable and an Imageview for the Bitmap and setViewVisibility to show only one View at once.